# CSS dropdown menu appears to be behind

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a HTML/CSS project and I made the fiddle here
[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m306cj62/)
I have the problem that whenever I hover the fields containing 14 and 00, the dropdown that shows will be underneath the `main-painel-inner` and i want it to be over it.
I have tried playing with the `z-index` property but I had no luck. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` from `.panel-header` prevents it to show underneath date picker

Comment: if you remove `overflow:hidden` from your `.panel .panel-header`, i think the hovered menu will be visible. if that's your question

Comment: Just as they say... https://jsfiddle.net/m306cj62/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes in style may help you

```
.main-panel
{
overflow:hidden;
}
.panel .panel-header
{
overflow:none; /* as none */
}
```